# Importar fuentes a Sass

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

¿Alguien sabe como importar fuentes que no sean de google font, osea que hayan sido descargadas a un archivo de Sass?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

puedes importar las fuentes de la misma manera en que se importan en css y aquí esta el codigo que puedes usar:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Name';
    src: url('./font.ttf');
}
```

Si deseas usar la fuente en algun otro archivo simplemente importa el archivo en donde defines la fuente:

```
@import './file';
```

Aquí hay una [guia de sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide) que lo puede explicar mejor que yo